# TFLite: Slow GPU/CPU synchronisation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu GPU/CPU can be very slow. Does anyone know why this is the case? What does such synchronisation actually involve?